# Redirect from one URL to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have following 2 URLs:

- www.xxxassistance.es
- www.xxxassistance.com

I need these both redirections:

- www.yyyprevencion.es  -> www.xxxassistance.es
- www.yyyprevencion.com -> www.xxxassistance.com

I am new using htaccess, and I tried this but doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xxxprevencion.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxassistance.es/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xxxprevencion.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxassistance.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Are the `</p>`'s actually in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but here are two scenarios I wrote solutions for. Try one of these in `.htaccess` depending on what you need:

> www.yyyprevencion.es -> www.xxxassistance.es
> www.yyyprevencion.com ->
>   www.xxxassistance.com

```
# www.yyyprevencion.es --> www.xxxassistance.es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yyyprevencion\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxassistance.es/$1 [L,R=301]

# www.yyyprevencion.com --> www.xxxassistance.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yyyprevencion\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxassistance.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

> www.xxxprevencion.es -> www.xxxassistance.es
> www.xxxprevencion.com ->
>   www.xxxassistance.com

```
# www.xxxprevencion.es --> www.xxxassistance.es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xxxprevencion\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxassistance.es/$1 [L,R=301]

# www.xxxprevencion.com --> www.xxxassistance.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xxxprevencion\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxassistance.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Experiment here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Oh, thanks for that URL to practice!! Very usefull but it doesnt works... I use xxxprevencion.com and .es but it says the condition was not met for both of them...

Comment: You wrote "www.yyyprevencion.es -> www.xxxassistance.es". Why are you typing in "xxxprevencion.com" then? I added two possible answers. Please check those, and maybe clarify what your are trying to do if those don't work please.